# Multiple configuration commands through vtysh

Tags: go, network-programming, openvswitch, quagga

I have device configuration saved in a file and use it to configure through vtysh.

```
config,err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Read err:")
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
cmd := exec.Command("vtysh", "-c", "configure terminal", "-c",string(config))
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("vtysh err:")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
} else {
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

Above code gives error:

```
vtysh err:
exit status 1
```

File contents :

```
vlan 1
    no shutdown
vlan 999
    no shutdown
```

If I paste the file contents into vtysh( config terminal context) then the commands do execute.

The vtysh commands that I'm trying to run:

```
switch# configure terminal
switch(config)# vlan 89
switch(config-vlan)# no shut
switch(config-vlan)# vlan 90
switch(config-vlan)# no shut
```

Comment: Can you please add more details, like what vtysh commands you are trying to run? Also, I suspect string(config) here returns the file contents which may not be compatible with the command.

Comment: @RaviTezu Done. If I copy the contents of the file into the vtysh config terminal context then it works fine. So, I'm thinking that it should be compatible.

Comment: I think, you still need to run the cmd.Run() to execute the command? And also, do you see any errors on the stderr? Also, can you please paste the whole script? Where is `filePath` declared? Can the script read the file? Can you check that `err` in the above code is nil?

Comment: @RaviTezu Added whole script. I've verified the file read. The stderr is the part of the combined output.